# When duplicate date values exist in a column, change the value of the oldest

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a query that returns records with duplicate Month and Year in a date field.  I need to identify the records with duplicate Month and Year, then identify the oldest based upon the full date and change the value of a column that displays the month based upon the date column to that month - 1.

Background:  The query grabs the last 12 bills for a customer.   In a few instances, the Date (actually the read date - which is typically the last day of the month) reflects when a meter was read.  The only time there could be read dates with the same month year in that 12 month period is when a read date (the last day of the month) falls on a non business day, then it pushes to the next month.  I'm looking for the usage in the month the meter was read for the last 12 months.

Example, in the query results below the highlighted month should read Feb as it is the oldest of the duplicate Mar 2017 results.

[image]

Comment: Why only the last row change?  What happen to other rows?

Comment: what happens if you have 3+ rows with the same Year/Month ... only the 'oldest' is changed? what if you have 2 rows with the identical 'oldest' date? what happens in your example if row #13 already has 2017/Feb?

Comment: Great questions.  The last row changes because it is the oldest record with duplicate Month Year values in the Date column.

Comment: @markp - If somehow 3+ rows have the same Year/Month, I'd have invalid data.  I've updated the post with some more info to hopefully clarify.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: What sql server and version are you you using?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP3) - 10.50.6000.34 (X64)

Comment: so for the given set of data, the line 12 `Date` column would remain as '2017-03-01' but the `Month` column would become 'Feb'; and in the case where a duplicate `Month` has a value of 'Jan', you'e need to also subtract one from the `Year` column (not displayed in your sample data) ... right? as a side note: I recommend you take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some ideas on how to improve your chances of getting a useful answer

Comment: @markp - Thanks for the assistance and the suggestion to review hot to ask a qood question.  It's been a while since I've posted, and I should have re-read it.  The op's post solves my issue.  Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* this solves your problem.

```
--demo setup
drop table if exists billing;
go
CREATE TABLE Billing
    ([BillDt] datetime, [BillMonth] varchar(3))
;

INSERT INTO Billing
    ([BillDt], [BillMonth])
VALUES
    ('2018-01-30', 'Jan'),
    ('2017-12-28', 'Dec'),
    ('2017-11-30', 'Nov'),
    ('2017-10-31', 'Oct'),
    ('2017-09-28', 'Sep'),
    ('2017-08-31', 'Aug'),
    ('2017-07-31', 'Jul'),
    ('2017-06-29', 'Jun'),
    ('2017-05-31', 'May'),
    ('2017-04-27', 'Apr'),
    ('2017-03-30', 'Mar'),
    ('2017-03-01', 'Mar')
;

--the solution
--With SQL Server looking at each row on the Billing table...
--if you can find a row where the month is the same as the 'current' row, but
--the day is greater than the 'current' row, update the BillMonth of the 'current'
--row to be the previous month of the 'current' row.
UPDATE b
SET BillMonth = Substring(datename(month, DATEADD(month, - 1, billdt)), 1, 3)
FROM Billing b
WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM Billing
        WHERE datepart(month, BillDt) = datepart(month, b.BillDt)
            AND datepart(day, BillDt) > datepart(day, b.BillDt)
        )

SELECT *
FROM billing
ORDER BY billdt desc
```

---

```
 BillDt                  | BillMonth |
|-------------------------|-----------|
| 2018-01-30 00:00:00.000 | Jan       |
| 2017-12-28 00:00:00.000 | Dec       |
| 2017-11-30 00:00:00.000 | Nov       |
| 2017-10-31 00:00:00.000 | Oct       |
| 2017-09-28 00:00:00.000 | Sep       |
| 2017-08-31 00:00:00.000 | Aug       |
| 2017-07-31 00:00:00.000 | Jul       |
| 2017-06-29 00:00:00.000 | Jun       |
| 2017-05-31 00:00:00.000 | May       |
| 2017-04-27 00:00:00.000 | Apr       |
| 2017-03-30 00:00:00.000 | Mar       |
| 2017-03-01 00:00:00.000 | Feb       |
```